# Assigning the date the next given date when it is NA

Tags: r

I have a data frame and i need all of the dates to be filled, some are NA and they will therefore have to be a best guess based on the other data. So here everytime we see a data = NA i want the last available date carried down to replace this NA value.

```
mydf
match                        date
liverpool/chelsea            20230808
spurs/arsenal                20230809 
newcastle/manu               NA
manu/liverpool               20230809
arsenal/chelsea              20230911
spurs/liverpool              NA
chelsea/fulham               NA
brighton/villa               20230912
```

So here the ones that are NA will be filled as 20230809, 20230811 and 20230811

Comment: `tidyr::fill(mydf, date)`